# Добавление объекта в массив объектов без перезаписи старых объектов

Tags: javascript, vue.js, объекты

Пишу todo на Vue, не могу разобраться с добавлением новых тудушек
При добавлении новая тудушка перезаписывает старую и они становятся одинаковыми
Если сделать просто массив строк а не объектов то все работает хорошо, и тудушки сами себя не перезаписывают, но мне нужно добавлять в массив объект с полями имя и текст
никак не могу понять в чем дело

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
   <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
   <div class="container" id="app">
      <div class="card">
         <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
         <div class="form-control">
            <input type="text" :placeholder="userName" v-model="userNameValue" @keypress.enter="addNewNote" />
            <input type="text" :placeholder="placeholderString" v-model="inputValue" @keypress.enter="addNewNote" />
         </div>
         <button class="btn" @click="addNewNote">Добавить</button>
         <hr />
         <ul class="list" v-if="notes.length !== 0">
            <li class="list-item" v-for="(note, i) in notes">
               <div>
                  <h2>{{ note.name }}</h2>
                  <div class="itemText">{{ note.text }}</div>
               </div>
               <button class="btn danger" @click="removeNote(i)">Удалить</button>
            </li>
            <hr />
            <li>
               <strong>Общее количество заметок: {{ notes.length }}</strong>
            </li>
         </ul>
         <div v-else>Заметок пока нет. Добавьте первую!</div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
   <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
const App = {
   data() {
      return {
         title: 'Заметки',
         userName: 'Введите ваше имя',
         placeholderString: 'Введите текст заметки',
         userNameValue: '',
         inputValue: '',
         noteItem: {},
         notes: [
            { name: 'Юрий', text: 'Юрий написал текст' },
            { name: 'Максим', text: 'Максим написал текст' },
            { name: 'Андрей', text: 'Андрей написал текст' },
         ]
      }
   },
   methods: {
      addNewNote() {

         if (this.inputValue !== '' && this.userNameValue !== '') {

            this.noteItem.name = this.userNameValue
            this.noteItem.text = this.inputValue

            this.notes.push(this.noteItem)

            this.userNameValue = ''
            this.inputValue = ''

            console.log(this.noteItem);
            console.log(this.notes);
         }
      },
      removeNote(i, event) {
         this.notes.splice(i, 1)
      }
   },
   computed: {

   },
   watch: {

   }
}

Vue.createApp(App).mount('#app')
```

Comment: Нужно создавать новый объект, а не использовать `this.noteItem`. Ссылка на объект одна и та же поэтому и перезписывает.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте добавить key в цикл

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]